# How to split a video up into <2.5GB parts with FFmpeg

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, scripting

I am trying to achieve a way to send large video files through Firefox Send.

Because Firefox Send has a 2.5 GB limit per file that one sends, I need to break up a video file into parts that are each less than 2.5GB.

Is there a relatively simple way to reliably split a video based on data limits using FFmpeg, rather than using duration? (Using duration would be unreliable, because different equal length portions of a video can be different sized)

EDIT 1: I apoligize for the lack of clarity, I was planning on using a Bash script using FFmpeg and ffsend. I was wondering if there is any way to do this through video processing rather than zip compression.

Comment: considered using 7zip? sadly you didn't specify any language. But zipping the file and send the splitted zip file would be your best bet i guess. Please try to provide as many usefull information as possible, ideally you take your time to read the [ask] section of our [help].

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/712893/how-to-split-a-video-file-by-size-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard utility [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html) is intended for precisely this sort of thing.

```
# sender does:

split -b 2500m file.mpg file.mpg__split_

# recipient downloads all the pieces and does:

cat file.mpg__split_* > file.mpg
```

A disadvantage of this procedure is that the individual parts are not usable.

An advantage is that the final output is **identical** to the original.